# Why can I no longer find spring beans after moving packages

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm following the tutorial for spring social, accessing facebook data from here https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/ and I have that running fine. However when I move my SpringBootApplication class to a separate package from my Controller and Component scan for that package I get an error that my Facebook bean can no longer be found.

My package structure:

com.example
|_app
|_controller

My app class:

```
package com.example.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan({"com.example"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
package com.example.controller;

import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionRepository;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Facebook;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.api.PagedList;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Post;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class FacebookController {

    private Facebook facebook;
    private ConnectionRepository connectionRepository;

    public FacebookController(Facebook facebook, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        this.facebook = facebook;
        this.connectionRepository = connectionRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String helloFacebook(Model model) {
        if (connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class) == null) {
            return "redirect:/connect/facebook";
        }

        model.addAttribute("facebookProfile", facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile());
        PagedList<Post> feed = facebook.feedOperations().getFeed();
        model.addAttribute("feed", feed);
        return "home";
    }

}
```

The error:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.controller.FacebookController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Facebook' that could not be found.

Why does this stop working when I move packages?

Comment: That should work fine if that was the *only* change you made. If so, do a full clean and rebuild, and if the problem persists, post your POM/`build.gradle`. As a side comment, it's best to make those fields `final`, and if you use Lombok you don't even have to write the constructor yourself.

Comment: How is your Facebook bean defined?  Is it automatically provided by virtue of some library on your classpath?

Comment: The error says that Spring found your controller, but could not find it's dependency (the Facebook class). Did you mess with the pom.xml file (or Gradle config)?

Comment: @Apokralipsa: That'd lead to a *compilation* error, not a runtime error.

Comment: @makoto what, if Spring social is in, but a Spring Boot starter is not? Just guesing, really. I dont have my computer with me and cannot check it :)

Comment: That should work, without any doubt. `@ComponentScan` is not needed. Clean, rebuild and check your project or if your IDE is giving some trouble, preferably compile your project from console.

Comment: So if I remove '@ComponentScan' I get the whitelabel error page because my controller isn't registered to forward to my html page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem. Everything was correct as the comments above state. I needed to run a maven clean on my project to fix the issue. An interesting thing I discovered: I always create a maven run configuration in intellij with both a clean and install in the command line. However this wasn't solving my issue. It wasn't until I did a clean by itself then rang the application's main method to regenerate the target did my issue get resolved. This will change how I run projects in the future going forward